# Are there any tools to manage the android project resources?

Tags: android, android-resources

Suppose we have ten different images for our projects.
We have created different sizes for each resolution (ldpi, mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi and xxhdpi).
After some tests, we decide to change the images background colour (or the red colour for a nice blue, or the shape, whatever).

How can I do it without modifying every image (in every directory)?
Are there any tools to help us in this task?

Solutions from Unix-like command line scripts till really heavy software are welcome.

Comment: Don't know if this could work for you but have you tried Android Asset Studio? http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/index.html

Comment: Do you mean change bg color programmatically? What kind of images are you trying to change, xml shapes, 9patch, standard PNG, JPG...?

Comment: @Neil, Android Asset Studio looks fine to generate new content (upload an image and download for all sizes), but I want to manage my current images. The ideal solution can be modify just one image and 'the unknown software' take care of apply the changes to all images.

Comment: @Kai, the background colour is just an example, I am looking for a tool to manage the image resources

Comment: Use a script (OSX, Linux) or batch with ImageMagick. Apply the change to highest dpi images, run the batch to create resized images for the rest. You will need to write some code however :]